# Making sure groups of radio buttons don't have the same value enabled

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple groups of radio buttons, 10 to be exact. With about 10 options. What I would like to do is make sure the user doesn't have like value 2 selected in one group and value 2 selected in another. I would really like to do this with out a hundred. if statements if possible. Any kind of examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is using jQuery possible option?

Answer (score 0):

Well the tricky thing is going to be picking which radio button in each group *should* be checked when you find out that one is checked incorrectly. (In my opinion, it's a bad UI design mistake to allow a group of radio buttons to have no button selected; that violates the behavioral model of real "radio buttons".) Assuming you can pick a random one, you can just handle "change" events (and "click" events too, if you want) on the radio buttons.  When an event fires, the handler should just check to see if there's any other radio button on the page with the same value that's also marked "checked". For each that's checked, you'd just find another radio button in its group to check instead.

I suppose if you wanted to you could pre-group clumps of radio buttons with like values so that you wouldn't have to search around the whole page on every click.  A hundred elements isn't really  that many however so such performance tweaks might not make any noticeable difference.

Comment: They all have something checked by default.

Comment: Right, but when one *changes*, and you need to make sure no others with like values are checked, then when you uncheck those some *other* button in each group should be checked. If the "default" checked button is always something with a unique value, then I guess that would work; just re-check whatever element is the default.